# Setting up a proxy server to make calls to API

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-functions, spfx

I am access third party API from javascript framework but it gives me **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**. After going through API documentation they suggested to **set up a proxy server to make calls to API behind the scenes**

It is really understandable that at the time API call we are passing some confidential parameters which will revel in JavaScript as it is client side

I am using azure, so on that basis somebody can guide me how we can create proxy server to make calls to API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the proxy feature in Azure Functions. It is really easy to get started with, an probably powerful enough to do what you need.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies